# C++20 concepts as Interfaces

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Hey I'm trying to design some Interfaces without any runtime overhead using c++20 concepts.

I came up with the following (simplified) concept

```
/**
 * @brief This concept defines an OSA Interface
*/
template<typename T, typename Task_T>
concept OSA_Layer_T = requires (T a) {
    {T::getName(a)} -> std::same_as<std::string>; ///< Returns the name of the task (if no name is available return the ID as string)
    {T::getId(a)} ->std::same_as<Task_T>;  ///< returns the (underlying) ID of the task
};
```

Since every OS has it's own internal Task Handle Type (and I do not want to use void*) I need to pass the actual Task Handle as a template parameter to my concept

However I'm unsure how to define a class using this template

I have tried the following

This does not work because Task_T is missing

```
template<typename String_Type_T, OSA_Layer_T TaskType_T>
class Foo
{
 
};
```

This does not work either

```
template<typename Task_T>
template<typename String_Type_T, OSA_Layer_T<Task_T> TaskType_T>
class Foo
{
    
};
```

Could you help me out here?
Thx :)

**Edit:**

To clarify:
This OSA is supposed to hide embedded RTOS. Most embedded RTOS (like FreeRTOS, EmbOS, RTX) are written in C, therefore the OSA class is just a collection of static members calling the actual RTOS functions written in C)
Usally you would implement this interface using virtual functions. However the goal of this is to reduce the overhead as much as possible. Usually on embedded targets we link statically, therefore all unused template functions are discarded automatically. Removing unused members is not possible if the members are virtual.

(CMSIS from ARM is available as an OSA for embedded RTOS. However IMHO CMSIS has some downsides like the overuse of void*. This is why I'd like to create a type safe OSA)

Comment: `template<typename String_Type_T, typename Task_T, OSA_Layer_T<Task_T> TaskType_T> class Foo` ?

Comment: "*`T::getName(a)`*" Why would a static member of a class take an instance of that class as a parameter? That's called "being a non-static member function", and you call those with `a.getName()`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I edited my question and added some explanations.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since every OS has it's own internal Task Handle Type (and I do not want to use `void*`) I need to pass the actual Task Handle as a template parameter to my concept

The second part of this doesn't actually follow from the first. If every OS has its own internal task handle type, the approach should be to have *that* be part of the concept. Because there is only one interface: `OSA_Layer_T`.

This might be easier to appreciate using a more familiar concept: iterators. Iterators have a type that they dereference to (this is, unfortunately, called `reference`. Unfortunate because it's not always a reference type, it could just be `int`). But you wouldn't want to define your concept this way:

```cpp
template <typename I, typename Reference>
concept Iterator = /* ... */;
```

Because it's not like `Iterator<int>` and `Iterator<string const&>` are different interfaces - if a type is an `Iterator`, then it has some `reference` type, which you should be able to ask for, and that doesn't really affect any of the rest of this.

This is typically called an *associated type*.

For the original question, the formulation should be:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept OsaLayer = requires (T a) {
    { T::getName(a) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;

    typename T::task_type;
    { T::getId(a) } -> std::same_as<typename T::task_type>;
};
```

If you need to be able to provide the task type *non-intrisuviely* (if you don't control the types that are `OsaLayer`), then you could do it this way:

```cpp
// specialize this for types that need to be OsaLayer's
template <typename T> struct task_type;
template <typename T> using task_type_t = typename task_type<T>::type;

template<typename T>
concept OsaLayer = requires (T a) {
    { T::getName(a) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;

    typename task_type_t<T>;
    { T::getId(a) } -> std::same_as<task_type_t<T>>;
};
```

Comment: thx for your detailed answer. This seams to work. However I have still trouble to applying the concept````template<typename String_Type_T, OsaLayer TaskType_T>
 class Foo
 {
 public:
  String_Type_T m_strFoo;
 };````



with 
```class FreeRTOSTask
{
public:
  std::string getName() const
  {
    return "";
  }
  TaskHandle_t getId() const
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
};```

```Foo<std::string, FreeRTOSTask> f;```
this will result in a compiler error
do you know why?

Comment: @JHeni Does `FreeRTOSTask` have a task type declared somewhere? In general, by the way, "this will result in a compile error do you know why?" is not a particularly helpful question - what compile error, where, what does it say, etc.?

Comment: @JHeni Also, `String_Type_T` is a really excessive naming convention. Do you really need both the `_T` and also the `_Type`?

Comment: nope i do not need the _T and the _Type ;) The compiler tells me that the concept requirements of Foo are not fulfilled when creating an instance of Foo with `FooClass<std::string, FreeRTOSTask>`. Another error is that template argument deduction failed for FooClass